# Show the function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Set $f(t)$ as a complex valued function on [0,1] s.t. $\int_0^1|f(t)|dt<\infty$. Show that $\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt$ defines an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$.

Comment: Try something. Look up Leibniz's rule.

Comment: Maybe a combination of Morera's theorem and Fubini's theorem could help?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687002/holomorphicity-of-fz-int-infty-infty-fracftt-zdt

Comment: Expand $\frac{1}{t-z}$ in power series of $z-a$ for $a$ outside $[0,1]$. Exchange integral and summation to obtain a convergent power series expansion. Done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{t-z}\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{t-z_0-(z-z_0)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{t-z_0}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z-z_0}{t-z_0}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{t-z_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z-z_0}{t-z_0}\right)^n\,\mathrm dt\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1\frac{f(t)}{(t-z_0)^{n+1}}\mathrm dt\right)(z-z_0)^n.\end{align}